# How to convert list to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I use `BeautifulSoup` to get some data from a webpage:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Media/Internet-users")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html5lib')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))

df.head()
```

But `df` is a list, not the pandas DataFrame as I expected from using `pd.read_html`.

How can I get pandas DataFrame out of it?

Comment: `read_html` returns a list of dataframes. So if you just take first element `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]`, shouldn't it work? Assuming your other code is correct in fetching the tables.

Comment: @KetanMukadam: Yes, it works as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) with your `url`:

```
df = pd.read_html("http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Media/Internet-users")[0]
```

And then if necessary remove `GRAPH` and `HISTORY` columns and replace `NaN`s in column `#` by forward filling:

```
df = df.drop(['GRAPH','HISTORY'], axis=1)
df['#'] = df['#'].ffill()
print(df.head())
   #                                       COUNTRY         AMOUNT  DATE
0  1                                         China    389 million  2009
1  2                                 United States    245 million  2009
2  3                                         Japan  99.18 million  2009
3  3  Group of 7 countries (G7) average  (profile)  80.32 million  2009
4  4                                        Brazil  75.98 million  2009

print(df.tail())

        #                                        COUNTRY AMOUNT  DATE
244   214                                           Niue   1100  2009
245  =215  Saint Helena, Ascension, and Tristan da Cunha    900  2009
246  =215                                   Saint Helena    900  2009
247   217                                        Tokelau    800  2008
248   218                               Christmas Island    464  2001
```

Comment: Hard question, it depends of webpage.

Comment: I think it depends of gotchas, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-html-gotchas)